# np.matmul() inside tf.py_func() throws SIGBUS error

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, bus-error

I am seeing a fatal error from matrix multiplication inside a `py_func` call.
In the `py_func` call I am multiplying a tensor with a set of 3D coordinates by a rotation matrix. This reproduces the error:

```
x = np.matmul(np.ones([640*480, 3]), np.eye(3))
```

When running outside a TF session this works with no problem, but inside the session when called via `py_func` I get

> Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Trying different tensor sizes I see that for a shape `(29000,3)` the line works, and for `(29200,3)` it fails.

I am using TensorFlow-1.12.0.

What could cause this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: How did you call it via `py_func` in tnsorflow session? We need to reproduce question.